# Batch script help, script exiting after parentheses

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I wrote a very simple script to output the host machine's MAC addresses to a text file.

The script is exiting right after line 3 - `'IF DEFINED WRITEOK ('.`

```
@echo off

cls

copy /Y NUL "%CD%\.writable" > NUL 2>&1 && set WRITEOK=1
IF DEFINED WRITEOK (
 rem ---- we have write access ----
 set DIR=%CD%\interfaces
 set FILE=%DIR%\%USERNAME%.txt
 IF NOT EXIST "%DIR%" (
  MKDIR "%DIR%"
  echo DIR '%DIR%' was created
 ) else (
  echo DIR '%DIR%' already exists
 ) for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr /i "Physical Host"') do (
  echo %%i >> "%FILE%"
  echo OUTPUT written to '%FILE%'
 )

) else (
 rem ---- we don't ----
 echo DIR '%DIR%' is not writable
)

echo.
echo DONE!
pause
```

Comment: 1.) what about removing `@echo off` to see what is happening? 2.) please describe precisely what is actually happening and what you expect to happen; 3.) the `for /f` command can't directly follow `)`; either add a `&` in between, or place `for /f` into the next line;

Comment: ..) & for /f.. works, now I have another issue. %CD%, %USERNAME% can and do contain spaces. I'm not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the FOR one line after the closing parenthesis :

```
...) 
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr /i "Physical Host"') do (...
```

you can't start a FOR with a closing parenthesis in front :

This will not work :

```
(echo 1
) for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do echo %%a
```

and this will work :

```
(echo 1
) 
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do echo %%a
```

**EDIT 1 :**

For the path variables containing space use double quote :

```
"%cd%"
```

when using it.

Comment: ..) & for /f.. works, now I have another issue. %CD%, %USERNAME%, %DIR% can and do contain spaces. I'm not sure how to handle that.